# When develop a mobile cryptocurrency wallet, is there any good practice to store private key?

Tags: wallet, private-key

As i know, some wallet like electrum store private keys in client filesystem with encrypted and other web wallet like ether metamask store it on browser storage. And in the mobile wallet, is there any good practice to store private key?